# 3-layer ASP.NET app - Need critique/advice

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

My current setup is a 3 layered application: UI > BLL > DAL. Each layer is set up as a separate project. The UI is an ASP.Net website and the BLL & DAL are Class Library projects.

I've shown some sample code from each of my layers. Hopefully you guys can critique my application design and give me some tips/pointers or I'm doing this wrong, steer me in the right direction. Thanks!

**DAL Method**:

```
public static object Get_UserId(string username)
{
    ConnectionSettings connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings();
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionSettings.ConnectionString);
    string sql = String.Format("select UserId from Users where Username = '{0}'", username);
    try
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
        return sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch
    {                
        throw new DALException("Unable to retreive User ID");
    }
    finally
    {
        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
```

**The BLL method responsible for retreiving User ID**:

```
 public static int GetUserId(string username)
 {
     try
     {
         int userId = Int32.Parse(UserDAL.Get_UserId(username).ToString());
         return userId;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw new BLLException(ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

**The call to the BLL from UI:**

```
try
{
    int id = UserBLL.GetUserId("bobloblaw");
    Response.Write(id);
}
catch (DALException dalEx)
{
    Response.Write(dalEx.Message);
}
catch (BLLException bllEx)
{
    Response.Write(bllEx.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Things I would change in your code/approach:

- log errors
- get rid of static service methods
- hide dll exceptions in ui. Catch it in BLL and log it/do something with it.
- change DLL so the method in BLL instead of:

`int userId = Int32.Parse(UserDAL.Get_UserId(username).ToString());`

would use:

`int userId = new UserDAL().Get_UserId(username);`

These are first things that come to my head.

Comment: What is the problem using static methods, since the BLL and DAL methods don't require any class variables?

Answer (score 2):

I'd second getting rid of the static methods. Data access should be instance based in my opinion.

My main grip however is that you are not using parameterized queries. This code:

```
string sql = String.Format("select UserId from Users where Username = '{0}'", username);
```

Should be:

```
string sql = @"select UserId from Users where Username = @username");
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, sqlConnection);
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
```

Doing this will mitigate your SQL Injection issue using `string.Format(...)`. I make it a habit of always using parameterized queries no matter if it's being passed data from data entry or not. There is just no reason not to.

Also in place of using `finally` wrap things up in a `using` statement to close and dispose your Data objects like `SqlCommand` and `SqlConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

1. I agree with [IAmDeveloper](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/3-layered-asp-net-app-need-critique-advice/3321#3321) that BLL method should be:

   ```
   int userId = new UserDAL().Get_UserId(username);
   ```
2. I agree with [Tim Meers](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3312/3-layered-asp-net-app-need-critique-advice/3911#3911) that you should use **parameterized queries**.
3. I would change the whole approach to the exceptions handling:

   - It's wrong to catch all exceptions in your `DAL.Get_UserId` and replace them with `DALException`. By doing so, you lose all information about the original exception, such as the stack trace, and only keep the message (which itself can be pretty useless sometimes). Instead, create change `BLLException` constructor to accept an inner exception:

     ```
     public BLLException (string message, Exception inner)
         : base (message, inner) { }
     ```

     and throw it accordingly:

     ```
     throw new BLLException ("Error getting user ID", ex);
     ```

     The inner exception then will be accessible through `InnerException` property.
   - You are trying to catch `DALException` in your UI layer but it will never occur because the business layer already replaces them with `BLLException`s.